# Is "points lift along surjections" equivalent to choice in the internal logic?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, categorical-logic

I'm wondering about the following proposition in the internal logic of a topos:

Given an epimorphism $e : E \to B$, then for every points $p : 1 \to B$, there is a point $\tilde{p} : 1 \to E$ for which $e\tilde{p} = p$.

Is this the same as the (internal) axiom of choice, ``all surjections have a section'' in the internal logic?

Comment: Surely this can't be true. What if $B$ doesn't have global support? Your proposition is vacuously true, no matter what $e : E \to B$ is and what maps $B \to E$ might exist!

Comment: Externally this would imply that full support splits, so its a least as strong as that. But I'm wondering about internally (which I don't have much intuition for). My guess was that "forall $p : 1 \to B$ ..." would be interpreted internally as a map $B^1 \to \cdots$.

Comment: Maybe I have a really bad nose for the internal logic though! Very likely.

Comment: On second thought, while I still think I have good reason to be suspicious, it's no longer clear that my objection ought to be enough to straightforwardly kill the conjecture.